# Display or not Apipie documentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm using [Apipie](https://github.com/Apipie/apipie-rails) on my Rails app. I'm also using [Cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) to manage authorizations according to user's status.

I was wondering if anyone has already try to join these 2 gems to allow users to see API documentation or not.

Basically, I'm wondering if there is any way to dismiss API Documentation according to variables.

Answer (score 0):

well yes you can. You should write you own check of the authorization, but have a look at the second answer here: https://github.com/Apipie/apipie-rails/issues/349